# Custom assembly resolve while building MAF pipeline

Tags: c#, .net, appdomain, maf, system.addin

I am working on system that needs to support different degree of isolation for plugins. I have chosen MAF, since it matches my needs, supports separate process isolation and AppDomain isolation out of the box.

The sample below uses the separate process isolation:

```
AddInStore.Rebuild(path);
...
var ap = new AddInProcess();
ap.Start();
var addin = token.Activate<MyAddInBase>(ap, AddInSecurityLevel.FullTrust);
```

However I have a problems with making MAF work with libs that are shared between host and the plugin. Lets assume, I have projects (with output dirs):

```
- My.MainApp                    -> /.
- My.AddIn.Hosting              -> /.
- My.AddIn.Shared               -> /.
- My.AddIn.Contract             -> /contracts
- My.PlugIn.HostSideAdapter     -> /HostSideAdapters
- My.PlugIn.PlugInSideAdapter   -> /PlugInSideAdapter
- My.PlugIn.AddIn               -> /AddInViews
- My.SamplePlugin               -> /addins/SamplePlugin
```

And the references

```
My.MainApp                  <- My.AddIn.Hosting     (copy local = true)

My.AddIn.Hosting            <- My.AddIn.Shared      (copy local = true)
                            <- My.AddIn.Contract    (copy local = false)

My.PlugIn.AddIn             <- My.AddIn.Contract    (copy local = false)

My.PlugIn.HostSideAdapter   <- My.AddIn.Hosting     (copy local = false)
                            <- My.AddIn.Contract    (copy local = false)

My.PlugIn.PlugInSideAdapter <- My.PlugIn.AddIn      (copy local = false)
                            <- My.AddIn.Contract    (copy local = false)

My.SamplePlugin             <- My.PlugIn.AddIn      (copy local = false)
                            <- My.AddIn.Contract    (copy local = false)
```

This gives me a clean build with single dlls in each pipeline directory, everything works fine, pipeline is build, valid and working.

Untill I add the problematic one:

```
My.AddIn.Shared     <- My.AddIn.Contract    (copy local = false)

My.AddIn.Hosting    <- My.AddIn.Shared      (copy local = false)

My.PlugIn.AddIn     <- My.AddIn.Shared      (copy local = false)
```

This introduces a problem, because My.PlugIn.AddIn project can not be included in pipeline because:

1. There is a problem during load of My.PlugIn.AddIn - dependency
   My.AddIn.Shared cannot be found (if AddInViews contains single dll
   with addin base)
2. Unable to cast transparent proxy to my IContract type - (when
   colyLocal=true and AddInViews contains more than 1 dll)

Also, it is worth to mention only single class in My.PlugIn.AddIn is  decorated with AddInBaseAttribute and shared assembly does not have a single one.

So, in both situations the addin cannot be loaded.
I wanted to solve the problem by my custom handlers for events

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve
```

before calling AddInStore.Rebuild but this affects only the domain that my host app is ruuning and does not affect the dommain "Add-In Model Discovery worker AD" that is created internally by 
System.AddIn.Hosting.AddInStore

Since this class is static there is no way to override creation of the domain. Also it does not provide any events that will allow me to access to the inner-domain resolve errors.
Is there any way to inject my custom assembly resolution rules or force the inner appDomain to inherit resolve events from my main one?

Comment: Are you sure your references are right?  The `Hosting` should not reference the `HostSideAdapter`.  That being said, shared assemblies across the pipeline will create problems down the line if you want to support any concept of backward compatibility.  If your addin and host both reference the same assemblies you will not be able version them independently

Comment: You are right, I messed the reference list in the post and introduced the loop between libs. I have verified the references and updated the question.

Comment: Hosting and AddIn shouldn't need references to Contract.  And the plugin definitely shouldn't be referencing the Contract.  The whole point of how the pipeline is laid out is to abstract the host from knowing too much about the pipeline and the plugins from knowing too much about the pipeline.  In doing this, you can version each of them independently and just update the adapters to support backward compatibility. By having the plugin know the contract currency, you break this.

Comment: Thank you, it looks like I did not understood the principles behind System.Addin correctly. I will revise my references. Thank you.